# multiTextLine interrupting button

Tags: android, android-layout

As cou can see from a picture text is interrupting Save button. So i want that button move down when it is reached by multiTextLine bottom. Is it posible with RelativeLayout?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKxEw.png

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:context=".DisplayContact" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="370dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" >
         <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:text="@string/note"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextNote"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextNote"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/ButtonBackground"
            android:onClick="run"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/update_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextNote"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextNote"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonUpdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:background="@color/ButtonBackground"
            android:text="@string/update"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonUpdate"
            android:background="@color/ButtonBackground"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: a bit too long example. Is all that realy needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is too many `RelativeLayout`s. I have removed them and modified to match your goal.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".DisplayContact" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/note"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextNote"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextNote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Aaaaaaaaa sssdf sf sdf sd f sdfsd fsdg dsgds dsfdsf sdf sd wefwef wef wefwe fw efwe fwe fwe fwe fwfw fw"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextName" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:onClick="run"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextNote"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextNote"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextNote"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonUpdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:text="@string/update"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonUpdate"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonUpdate"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonUpdate" />

        </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scrollview` for that textview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="@string/flower"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/princess_flower"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
       android:text="@string/instructions" />

</ScrollView>
```

This code is working fine for me. see this picture below and modify to your need.[image: Scrollview for image description]

Comment: where i should put it?